# Using `.C` Interface of R to handle read/write files

Tags: r, c

I am trying to filter a huge txt file line by line, which pure `R` is not so good at. So, I wrote a c function that hopefully can speed up the process. Below is a **minimum working example** of `filter.c`, just for the demo purpose.

Currently, I have tried `.C` to do the trick without luck. Here is my attempt.

1. built `filter.so` using `gcc -shared -o lfilter.so -fPIC filter.c`
2. `dyn.load("lfilter.so")`
3. `.C("filter", as.character("I1.txt"), as.character("I1.out.txt"), as.character("filter.txt"))`

`R` crashed on me with 3rd step. But unfortunately, I have to stay within R.

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

### filter.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LL 256

int get_row(char *filename)
{
  char line[LL];
  int i = 0;
  FILE *stream = fopen(filename, "r");
  while (fgets(line, LL, stream))
  {
    i++;
  }
  fclose(stream);
  return i;
}


void filter(char *R1_in,
            char *R1_out,
            char *filter)
{
  char R1_line[LL];
  
  FILE *R1_stream = fopen(R1_in, "r");
  FILE *R1_out_stream = fopen(R1_out,"w");
 
  /*****************loading filters*******************/
  int nrows = get_row(filter);
  
  FILE *filter_stream = fopen(filter, "r");
  
  char **filter_list = (char **)malloc(nrows * sizeof(*filter_list));
  for(int i = 0; i <nrows; i++)
  {
    filter_list[i] = malloc(LL * sizeof(char));
    fgets(filter_list[i], LL, filter_stream);
  }
  
  fclose(filter_stream);
  
  /*****************filtering*******************/
  
  while (fgets(R1_line, LL, R1_stream))
  {
    // printf("%s", R1_line);
    
    for(int i = 0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
      if(strcmp(R1_line, filter_list[i])==0)
      {
        fprintf(R1_out_stream, "%s", R1_line);
        break;
      } 
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  
  for(int i=0; i<nrows; i++)
  {
    free(filter_list[i]);
  }
  free(filter_list);
  
  fclose(R1_stream);
  fclose(R1_out_stream);
  
}

// int main()
// {
//   char R1_in[] = "I1.txt";
//   char R1_out[] = "I1.out.txt";
// 
//   char filters[] = "filter.txt";
// 
//   filter(R1_in, R1_out, filters);
//   return 0;
// }
```

### I1.txt

```
aa
baddf
ca
daa
```

### filter.txt

```
ca
cb
```

### Expected Output I1.out.txt

```
ca
```

Comment: If you ask about the `.C()` interface you are not using `Rcpp` so I edit out the tag.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You are right. I thought an Rcpp expert may have some suggestions.

Comment: My $0.02:  i) Filter the file on the command-line via `awk` or `sed` which are powerful.  ii) Use `data.table::fread()`.  You and I will not beat it with simple (and single-threaded) code.

Comment: Although it's not a bad idea to filter with `awk/sed` but it is 2022 so I'd use `perl/python` ;-) But, how is the C code crashing? You're not checking the return of `fopen` calls for `NULL`. Can you step into the code with a debugger?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for your advice on command-line and `fread`. Although it is a single thread now, I plan to make it to multiple threads to process multiple files inside R. To be honest, memory consumption is one of my concerns too. If I do filter after loading everything into RAM with parallel computing, it may consume more than 50GB. That's why I prefer to use file streaming to filter instead.

Comment: An alternative approach that's worth trying is `pipe("awk -f filter.awk < I1.txt", "r")` -- this is the equivalent of C `popen`.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks, unfortunately, I have to stay with R as the whole project is in R right now. I would try the debugger and see what I can find.

Comment: @zwol Thanks, I would try it. The demo is just a minimal example, the actual code is a bit more complicated than this.

Comment: Are you sure R and you agree on the current directory?

Comment: @Neil Well, I used `dyn.load("lfilter.so")` with no error.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: I was thinking "I1.txt", ... could be in another directory then the one you assume. Since you don't check, I thought this would lead to the behaviour you experience. Possibly fixable using absolute paths? This is guessing, I didn't RTM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had never used R before. But, I was a bit intrigued. So, I installed R and did a little research.

Everything in R [using the `.C` interface] is passed to the C function as a pointer.

From: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/02/three-ways-to-call-cc-from-r/ we have:

> Inside a running R session, the .C interface allows objects to be directly accessed in an R session’s active memory. Thus, to write a compatible C function, ***all arguments must be pointers***. No matter the nature of your function’s return value, it too must be handled using pointers. The C function you will write is effectively a subroutine.

So, if we pass an integer, the C function argument must be:

```
int *
```

I took a guess that:

```
char *
```

Needed to be:

```
char **
```

And, then tested it with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHOW(_sym) \
    show(#_sym,_sym)

static void
show(const char *sym,char **ptr)
{
    char *str;

    printf("%s: ptr=%p",sym,ptr);

    str = *ptr;
    printf(" str=%p",str);

    printf(" '%s'\n",str);
}

void
filter(char **R1_in,char **R1_out,char **filt)
{

    SHOW(R1_in);
    SHOW(R1_out);
    SHOW(filt);
}
```

---

Here is the output:

```
> dyn.load("filter.so");
> .C("filter",
+   as.character("abc"),
+   as.character("def"),
+   as.character("ghi"))
R1_in: ptr=0x55a9f8cb1798 str=0x55a9f9de9760 'abc'
R1_out: ptr=0x55a9f8cb1818 str=0x55a9f9de9728 'def'
filt: ptr=0x55a9f8cb1898 str=0x55a9f9de96f0 'ghi'
[[1]]
[1] "abc"

[[2]]
[1] "def"

[[3]]
[1] "ghi"

> q()
```

---

So, you want:

```
void
filter(char **R1_in, char **R1_out, char **filt)
{

    FILE *R1_stream = fopen(*R1_in, "r");

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Respect for your research spirit. I will test it out asap and let you know how it goes.